# Longest path in a weighted cyclic digraph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have a weighted cyclic digraph with no more than 30 nodes. Theoretically, there's no restriction on the number of arcs, but it'd be ok if I had to cap it at 1230. I need to find the path with the largest overall weight where no vertex is visited more than once. It is, however, allowed for vertices not to be visited at all. All of the weights will be positive. Is it possible to do this in polynomial time?

Edit: The weights on the edges will not all be 1, they will be ranging from 1-100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the edge weights have weight 1, then directed Hamiltonian path problem reduces to this special case, so there is no polynomial time algorithm for a general graph (assuming NP$\not =$P). (Same if the weights are on the nodes.)

However, since your graph is small, and presumably special in structure, it may be possible to solve your problem.

- If you don't need guarantees on optimality, you can formulate the problem as an integer program and then use one of the *extremely good* optimization software packages. Some relevant ideas are described here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16647/hamiltonian-cycle-as-an-integer-linear-programming-problem
- You may also have luck with dynamic programming, if the graph has low treewidth (i.e. if it is not too far from being a tree): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895600920318